# Different scroll speed for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I'm trying to create a parallax effect and I'm in need of help. How can I slow down the scroll speed for different elements on my page? I should also add that I've downloaded skrollr but even on their tutorial didn't find anything mentioning scroll speed.

Thank you

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 14):

There is no direct way to influence the scroll speed of the site. That is directed by the Browser and the OS itself. There are ways to fake it by setting your contents scroll as seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36dp03ur/).

If you are aiming for a simple paralaxx effect w3schools has a [great demo/tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp).

I think what you are looking for is an effect like [this](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/). You can do this with CSS transformations.

```css
  .parallax {
    height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    perspective: 300px;
  }

  .parallax__group {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  .parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .parallax__group {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
  }

  .parallax__layer--fore {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
    transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .parallax__layer--base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 4;
  }

  .parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .parallax__layer--deep {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    z-index: 2;
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group3" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore">
        <div class="title">Foreground Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group4" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--deep">
        <div class="title">Deep Background Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group5" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore">
        <div class="title">Foreground Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group6" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group7" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested it out and it worked just fine. And it's exactly what I'm looking for. It's a lot to take in however, could you break it down for me and explain how all of these work together if you don't mind?

Comment: you can affect scroll speed using CSS only by using translateZ and setting perspective on scrollable parent https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/