# Is it possible to slow down scroll speed in Safari?

Tags: ios, scroll, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, capacitor

We have a big table inside "overflow: auto" div. Now we are packing our PWA in Capacitor app and we've noticed that in mobile Safari on iOS a scroll speed is too high.
Yeah, you can control the speed with a finger but even the initial speed is too high

Is it even possible to slow down scroll speed on one element or on the whole site in Safar?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821213/different-scroll-speed-for-each-element) answer your question ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.